# re.match does not work ,throws error that 're' is not recognized in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
m=re.match('bat,'bat').group()
```

gives `name error:name 're' is not defined`
so in which versions of python does it work

```
b='bat|bit'
m=re.search(b,'bit)
name Error:name 're' is not defined`
```

so i think re module does not work with in my python version,i have tried it in UBUNTU also there also it shows the same errors.i have active state python.

Comment: Do you have `import re` ?

Comment: no i did not ,please tell how can we know various modules that exist in python library

Comment: @SaranshGupta, we look [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `import re` before you use `re`.  Modules don't work if you don't import them, alas.

Comment: If you really want magic auto-import in your interactive sessions, ipython can do that. Although I think that's no longer an advertised feature, because it's not a great idea.